# Angular 14 how to get an error caught by an interceptor or global error handler back to the original page

Tags: angular

So I have tried using both an error interceptor and the Global error handler, but I cannot get the error back to my original page. I want to be able to display to the user the error on the page. In my test case, I'm forcing a server side error.

So I have created the following RouteMessageService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RouteMessageService {
  private _message: string = '';

  get message(): Observable<string> {
    const returnedMessage = this._message;
    this.clear();

    return of(returnedMessage);
  }

  set messages(val: string) {
    this._message = val;
    console.log("in Router Message : " + val);
  }

  clear() {
    this.messages = '';
  }
}
```

Then in my interceptor I have the following:

```
......
 private handleServerSideError(error: HttpErrorResponse): boolean {
    let handled: boolean = false;

    switch (error.status) {
      case 400:
        this.routeMessageService.messages = "Data would be truncated: please try again.";
        console.log("got here 2: " + error.message);
        handled = true;
        break;
       
    }
    return handled;
  }
```

This gets hit and the message is correctly set in my RouteMessageService.

In the code behind for my page I pass the service in on my constructor have:

```
constructor(private errorService: RouteMessageService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService) {
```

and I declare a variable:

```
msg: Observable<string> = this.errorService.message;
```

then in the page I have:

```
{{ msg | async}}
```

The message never gets shown. The behaviour is the same if I use the global error handler as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Subject() in your messageService and subscribe to it in required component.

```
const messages= new Subject<string>();   


this.routeMessageService.messages.next("Data would be truncated: please try again.");
```

Comment: If I try and change my code as per your example i get the error 'next' doesn't exist on property string

Comment: Your variable declaration should look like this:


private _message: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();